# PouchDB 4.0.3 : Uncaught (In promise) when I call info() on unreachable database

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

Since PouchDB 4.0.3, when I do this :

```
var remoteDbInstance = new PouchDB(*myCouchDbUrl*);

remoteDbInstance.info().then(function (resRemoteInfo) {
    console.log(resRemoteInfo);   
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

if myCouchDbUrl respond : OK
but if myCouchDbUrl is unreachable : I obtain

*Uncaught (In promise)*

in chrome console...

An idea ?

Thks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in PouchDB. Could you file a test case on Github? The error is definitely supposed to show up in your `catch()` function.

*Edit*: OK, I can confirm, and I've filed a bug: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4358